# istringstream Confusion not returning correct value

Tags: c++

I am struck on getting this to work.  What I am trying to do is:

Read a complete line from `cin` and scans it as an `integer` (using the string streams). If the scan succeeds, the integer value is returned. If the argument is not a legal integer or if extraneous characters (other than whitespace) appear in the string, the user is given a chance to reenter the value. Both the prompt and reprompt arguments are optional.

If supplied, the optional prompt string is printed before reading the value. If the prompt does not end with a space, a space is added when printing it.
If supplied the optional reprompt string is used as an error message when the input is not acceptable. If no reprompt string is supplied, then the string "Invalid integer format. Try again: " is used.

Prototype is:

```
int getInt(const string& prompt,
    const string& reprompt){

    int n;
    bool pass = true;

    while (pass != false){

        string line = getLine(prompt);
        istringstream s(prompt);

        s >> n >> ws;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){

            if (i == ': '){
                return isdigit(n);

            }
            else if (i != ': '){
                i++;
                line = i + ' ';

            }


        }
        if (s.fail() || !s.eof()){

            cerr << reprompt;
            pass = false;
        }

    }
    return n;
}
```

The results:

```
 3. Make sure getInt returns values correctly
Invalid integer format. Try again:    X Calling getInt("123")->123: 
expected [123] but found [-858993460]
```

Comment: You initialize the string input stream from the *prompt*, not the line you just read.

Comment: But I have to admit I don't quite follow in your validation loop. `i` is a position in the `line`variable, right? Not a character? Not a string? But you treat it as *both* a character *and* a string.

Comment: -1 for not posting real code. `>> ws;` what's `ws` actually? What it's purpose should be?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/ws/

Comment: @Hidden I don't give much about the cplusplus.com reference. It's well known to be outdated, and even giving wrong informations. I way off prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) actually.

Comment: just drop that useless `for (size_t i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)` loop

Comment: Your compiler should warn you about the multi-character "character" `': '` (which you're comparing to the loop index for some reason), and `isdigit` applies to single *characters*, not numbers, *and* `i + ' '` adds 32 to `i` — it does not append a space to a number — *and* `line = i + ' ';` won't even compile, so this is obviously not the code you're running.

Comment: In one place you return a booleanish (return from std::isdigit()) and in another you return an int...

Answer (score 1):

Comments don't handle code very well, so I write this as an answer instead.

What you seem to want to do is to write a function that reads a line from some input stream, and then parse it as an integer while verifying that an actual integer var input?

Then you *start* okay, but then in the parsing/validation you kind of mess up.

All you have to do is e.g.

```
std::string line = getLine(prompt);
for (;;)
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    int n;
    if (iss >> n)  // This does both parsing and validation
        return n;

    // If we reach here, input was not an integer

    line = getLine(reprompt);
}
```

Comment: I think you need `if((iss >> n >> std::ws).eof())` to ensure there are no other spurious characters following the number.

Comment: @Galik: Please search StackOverflow for "c++ eof wrong" to find out why Joachim is correct.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am well aware of the errors of looping on `eof()`. Try my solution and see. The results speak for themselves. And by that I mean try validating "3a" or "5   dfg" with each solution.